# How do I stay logged in to Bloomberg with webscraper, then scrape an article's full content fast?

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, jwt, session-cookies, bloomberg

## Overall Objective

Using nodeJS, I want to be able to log in with user credentials into Bloomberg, then scrape as a logged in user. Preferably not with Selenium because Selenium in my experience is slow.

## My question is, how do I login to Bloomberg, stay logged in, and use that login to scrape the full content of an article?

Anyone done this before or know an alternate approach to suggest?

It'd also be really useful to know how to do this without having to login for every article I need to scrape.

## Current Approach

I'm currently able to scrape non-paywalled content without logging in through Axios.get and specifying a user-agent + Cheerio (for easy .class selector).

I use this article https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-06-28/doordash-introduces-hourly-minimum-rate-option-for-dashers. Without logging in you get 2 paragraphs, but with a log in that has the Bloomberg subscription there are 7 paragraphs.

## What's not working

However, I'm not able to submit a POST request to Bloomberg with https://www.bloomberg.com/account/signin. Here's how I tried to do that:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CookieJar } from 'tough-cookie';
import { wrapper } from 'axios-cookiejar-support';

const cookieJar = new CookieJar();
const client = wrapper(axios.create({ cookieJar }));

const loginData = {
  username: 'my_username',
  password: 'my_password'
};

// login
client.post('https://www.bloomberg.com/account/signin', loginData, {
    jar: cookieJar,
    withCredentials: true
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
      console.log("path1")
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in Node.js
      console.log(error.request);
      console.log("path2")
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
      console.log("path3")
    }
    console.log(error.config);
    console.log("path4");
});
```

I also tried to see what URL the page sent the POST request to, but there wasn't any POST request I could find when submitting credentials to the page (only GET requests). Why would there be no POST request sent? Even if its a single page application I feel like it should still be sending some kind of POST to verify login.

I got 405 error code (path1) meaning the URL doesn't support the method of request I made.(POST?) Also got error.config (path4), but I think that's secondary to the 405 error code.